# problem compiling a switch case statement in chisel

Tags: hdl, chisel

I was writing a simple switch-case for my state machine. However, after calling `sbt test` I receive the following error:

[image]

Comment: Please, add error traces in text, not as screenshot picture. And give us the source code that fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very important to include the version of Chisel and your code when asking a question, but fortunately this one rings a bell as https://github.com/chipsalliance/chisel3/pull/1595.

You can workaround this by importing `chisel3.util._`. The better solution would be to update your version of Chisel, this bug is fixed in versions v3.2.8, v3.3.3, and v3.4.0 (and newer).